# GXT3 Checkbox Tree with some checkbox checked

Tags: gxt

I am new to GXT3, and I am now working with the CheckBoxTree based on
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:checkboxtree

I would like to let some checkbox checked after rendering.
1) Do setCheckedSelection`(List<BaseDto> selection)` help?
2) If yes, what to include inside `List<BaseDto>` selection?

Thanks as i have already stuck for serveral days

Comment: You include the records that you want to be selected (from the TreeStore).

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer comes late but since I got this question as one of the first google search results, I'm giving the answer below.

The setCheckedSelection() is correct and you have to pass there the List of BaseDto which are to be selected.